# android.preference.Preference.setOnPreferenceClickListener() does not work

Tags: android, android-preferences

I want to set an intent from my SettingsFragment (extends PreferenceFragment) to another activity within my app. I tried using the following code at first: (I'm using android.preference.Preference)

**preferences.xml** (the root preferences)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    ...
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="About">

        <Preference
            android:key="about_here"
            android:title="About us"
            android:enabled="true" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Then, in my **SettingsFragment.java**:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    public static final String goToAbout = "about_here";
    private ViewGroup parent;
    private View currView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
                Preference preferencex = findPreference(goToAbout);
        preferencex.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AboutActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("Class", "Settings");
                preference.setIntent(i);
                Log.e("Preference", "Clicked");
                getActivity().startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

However, the onPreferenceClick code is not invoked at all (I know from the Log.e() that it does not happen). I know that many have asked this question before, but even implementing their solutions does not help. Is there anything I'm missing?

Also, I don't mind implementing an Intent from within preferences.xml, but I tried that and it returns an error.